# return to main after paying

Tags: c#, sql-server, forms, printing

i have POS system to fastfood, created by c# and sql server.
after the payment process show me window "Order Successfully Paid" after clicking to ok return to form ProductsReceiptPreview again,
i want after payment process go to the form main.
this is my code.......

---

```
       private void lblPayments_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if (pnlPayments.Height != lbl.Height)
            {
                pnlPayments.Height = lbl.Height;
                btnDone.Text = "DONE";
                lbl.Text = "RECEIPT";
                btnDone.Image = Resources.done;
                Data.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                pnlPayments.Height = 394;
                btnDone.Text = "RECEIPT";
                lbl.Text = "AMOUNT";
                btnDone.Image = Resources.receipt;
                Data.Hide();
            }


    }

    private void Touch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = (Button)sender;
        txtCashReceived.Text += btn.Text;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if(txtCashReceived.Text.Length >0)   txtCashReceived.Text = 
     txtCashReceived.Text.Remove(txtCashReceived.Text.Length - 1);
    }


    double totalBill = 0;
    private void btnPay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtCashReceived.Text.Length > 0 && totalBill <= 
    Convert.ToInt32(txtCashReceived.Text) && Data.RowCount > 0)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var rep in ListReports)
            {
                i++;
                var report = new ModelReports();
                report.Productname = rep.Productname;
                report.TotalSales = rep.TotalSales;
                report.TotalTransactions = rep.TotalTransactions;
                report.Save();


            }

            var rpd = new ProductsReceiptPreview(dataReceiptBindingSource, 
            txtTotal.Text, txtCashReceived.Text, txtChange.Text);
            rpd.ShowDialog();
            if (i == ListReports.Count)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Order Successfully Paid");
            }
            pnlProducts.Controls.Clear();
            pnlCategoryPanel.Visible = false;
            dataReceiptBindingSource.Clear();
            LoadTables();
            btnDone.PerformClick();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please pay your order.");
            txtCashReceived.Text = "0";

        }
    }

    private void btnPay_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (txtCashReceived.Text.Length > 0 && totalBill <= 
        Convert.ToInt32(txtCashReceived.Text) && Data.RowCount > 0)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var rep in ListReports)
            {
                i++;
                var report = new ModelReports();
                report.Productname = rep.Productname;
                report.TotalSales = rep.TotalSales;
                report.TotalTransactions = rep.TotalTransactions;
                report.Save();


            }
            if (i == ListReports.Count)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Order Successfully Paid");
                txtCashReceived.Text = "0";
            }
            pnlProducts.Controls.Clear();
            pnlCategoryPanel.Visible = false;
            dataReceiptBindingSource.Clear();
            LoadTables();
            btnDone.PerformClick();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please pay your order.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: See my two form project.

Comment: Have you tried simply Close() ing it?

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

If you call some code from main then it will return to main when the call is finished. In the case of a Form, it's handled on a different thread started from main. The thread will never return back to main in this context. If you are using a click event to do some action and want to call some other code when that happens, then you need to re-design your infrastructure. Look into SOLID development principles and dependency injection.
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1033646/SOLID-Principle-with-Csharp-Example
https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windowsformsintegration.html

Comment: I'm not used click event, Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: We don't know your program, only you do. You pasted 5 click events in your code. I do not understand your program or what you want to do next... Your problem is not clear. We can help you solve a specific problem but you need to use your intuition to understand what that specific problem is. From the information you provided I can't identify any one specific problem you are having but more-so it feels like you're saying "Write it/Fix it for me".